# Lua - can't access key value. Always returns table

Tags: lua, scope, love2d, key-pair, expected-exception

So I've run into a few identical problems with Eclipse and Lua and Love2D.

In these cases, I've created a table, say fonts. It's in `main.lua`. In `fonts{}`, I create key pairs like this:

```
fontsize = 24
gFonts{
    ['smallFont'] = love.graphics.newFont('fontfile.ttf', fontsize)
}
```

Then I try to get the height of the font later using Love2D's `font.getHeight(self)`. I do that like this:

```
local fontSize = gFonts['smallFont'].getHeight(self)
```

But it doesn't work. It tells me that `getHeight` is expecting a Font, but I'm giving it a Table. That's obviously not true, because Eclipse brings up the autocomplete for `getHeight:Font` when I press period after `gFonts['smallFont']`.

So then I tried assigning the `smallFont` to a variable called `msgFont` and accessing `getHeight` from that. Nope, didn't work. I even erased 'self'. No fix.

I also tried `love.graphics.getHeight(fontcodehere)`, and it sort of works... but it grabs the height of the entire window, not the font.

I did manage to get it working, but I don't understand why this works and why the double font reference is necessary. I used:

```
local msgFont = gFonts['small']
local fontSize = msgFont.getHeight(gFonts['small'])
```

Why does this work? I understand the `msgFont` part or putting the font in the `getHeight` - *separately*...
But why do they need to be used together?

Isn't,

```
table['key'] == 'value'
```

?

Why does it return a table and not a Love2D font object / registry?
And why would I call

`getHeight()` and pass it itself as a table?

Why can't I call

`getHeight()` and pass it self?

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question - I've never had a formal programming education, and I get the feeling this has something to do with scope that I just don't understand properly. Maybe self isn't referring to the font, but to getHeight? How does that work?

Comment: Try `gFonts['smallFont']:getHeight()`.

Comment: Oh my god... I am an absolute idiot. I can't help but laugh. It's always the most simple things.

Answer (score 2):

Lua does not provide an object-oriented system but it does provide an optional syntax that makes using one a bit easier.

A "method" is a function with the context of a table passed in. It is a matter of intent. In all other respects, it is an ordinary function.

It *can* be defined with the `function expression : identifier ( … )` syntax. If so, there is an implicit first formal parameter with the name of `self`.

It *can* be called with the `expression : identifier ( … )` syntax. If so, the value of `expression` is passed as the first actual argument.

`getHeight` is a function that needs a context. So,

```
gFonts['small']:getHeight()
```

which is the same as:

```
local msgFont = gFonts['small']
msgFont.getHeight(msgFont)
```

which is in effect the same as your:

```
local msgFont = gFonts['small']
local fontSize = msgFont.getHeight(gFonts['small'])
```

BTW—Since 'small' is a valid identifier, you could write:

```
gFonts.small:getHeight()
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct call is `gFonts['smallFont']:getHeight()`.